# Stylus: a hash key for multiple values isn't compiling

Tags: css, stylus

In Stylus, how can we assign a hash key to a list of values? None of the following ways are working for me, it won't compile:

```
main-content-font = {
  family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif,
  size: 1em
}
```

```
main-content-font = {
  family: ("Noto Sans", sans-serif),
  size: 1em
}
```

```
main-content-font = {
  family: ("Noto Sans" sans-serif),
  size: 1em
}
```

```
main-content-font = {
  family: "Noto Sans" sans-serif,
  size: 1em
}
```

```
main-content-font = {
  family: "Noto Sans" sans-serif
  size: 1em
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't note how you were calling it, but here are 2 alternatives:

Encasing the whole thing in single quotes and calling it with `unquote` should get you there:

```
main-content-font = {
  family: '"Noto Sans", sans-serif',
  size: 1em
}

.selector {
  font-family unquote(main-content-font[family]);
  .subselector {
    font-size main-content-font[size];
  }
}
```

[Confirm in the stylus REPL](https://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=main-content-font%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20family%3A%20%27%22Noto%20Sans%22%2C%20sans-serif%27%2C%0A%20%20size%3A%201em%0A%7D%0A%0A.selector%20%7B%0A%20%20font-family%20unquote(main-content-font%5Bfamily%5D)%3B%0A%20%20.subselector%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20font-size%20main-content-font%5Bsize%5D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D).

As would creating a variable with the font family there, referencing it in the hash, and then calling the hash member without an additional function:

```
sansserif = "Noto Sans", sans-serif

main-content-font = {
  family: sansserif,
  size: 1em
}
```

[Also viewable in the REPL](https://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=sansserif%20%3D%20%22Noto%20Sans%22%2C%20sans-serif%0A%0Amain-content-font%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20family%3A%20sansserif%2C%0A%20%20size%3A%201em%0A%7D%0A%0A.selector%20%7B%0A%20%20font-family%20main-content-font%5Bfamily%5D%3B%0A%20%20.subselector%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20font-size%20main-content-font%5Bsize%5D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D).